# How are these return statements different

Tags: python, python-2.7

Take these two sample code statments:

```
result = []
return result.append(feed.entries[0])
```

&

```
result = []
result.append(feed.entries[0])
return result
```

The first gives me an error because the method that result is passed to complains of a NonType not being iterable. Why is this? To me both statements are equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `append` method of a list does not return anything

```
>>> a = []
>>> type(a.append(12))
<type 'NoneType'>
```

So when you're doing:

```
return result.append(feed.entries[0])
```

You're actually returning `None` in all cases, whereas when you do:

```
result.append(....)
return result
```

you're returning the list after it has been mutated (modified) hence giving a the expected result.

Comment: How does the second return None?

Comment: The second statement given by OP does not return None but the list itself after it has been mutated.

Comment: How does `you're actually returning None in all cases` make sense then?

Comment: What I've wanted to say (even if I badly did it) is that if a function uses `return result.append(feed.entries[0])` it will always return the `None` pointer.